# Android Studio, Unable to migrate to AndroidX

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx

I'm having the following error message when trying to do `refactor -> migrate to AndroidX`

> The gradle plugin version in your project build.gradle file needs to
>   be set to at least com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0 in order to
>   migrate to AndroidX

Although I have version higher specified in build.gradle...

`app/android/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
```

I have another `app/android/app/build.gradle`.

[image]
[image]

Comment: it might be looking for it in the root project's `build.gradle`.

Comment: it is the root project's build.gradle .. I have another at `app/android/app/build.gradle`

Comment: it happens to me even the gradle plugin is 4.0.0

Comment: Try this method:---> https://stackoverflow.com/q/62921341/13820568

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by changing version to `3.4.1` and back to `3.4.2`.
now error is gone..

Comment: Not a bad idea but it didn't work for me. I am now set to 3.4.2 and it still says my build.gradle file needs to be above 3.2.0 but what setting in my build.gradle file would that be?

Answer (score 0):

in my case,
apply
`classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1")`

instead of
`classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:${version.gralde}")` -> even `version.gralde` is 4.0.1

:thinking :) maybe android studio can't identity the plugin version if it references to an external value

Answer (score 0):

Only change gradle version of a project may be not enough. Please also check gadle versions of the dependies. Make sure every gradle version of a depency is beyond 3.2.0. Have a try, please.